# Custom ionicModal Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework

I am trying to create an Ionic Modal directive so that for each modals in the app I need not have to load the template and specify the close,open functions in the controller . I first created the below service

```
function ModalService($ionicModal) {

    this.initialize=function($scope,parent) {
        parent.modal = Array();

        angular.forEach( parent.modals , function(k){
            $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/'+k+'.html',function(modal)
                {
                    parent.modal[k]=modal;

                },
                {
                    scope:$scope,
                    animation:'slide-in-up'
                });
        });

        // Execute action on hide modal
        $scope.$on('modal.hidden', function () {
            // Execute action
        });
        // Execute action on remove modal
        $scope.$on('modal.removed', function () {
            // Execute action
        });

    };

    this.open=function(parent,k) {
        parent.modal[k].show();
    }

    this.close=function(parent,k) {
        parent.modal[k].hide();
    }
}
```

So , in the controller to load the templates I wrote ,

```
this.modals = ['add-item','edit-item'];

ModalService.initialize($scope,this);
```

But the same template might have input fields filled if the scope has values .
And So , I created the directive **customModal** directive to specify like this ,

```
<label custome-modal modal-name="add-item" for="" class="item item-input item-floating-label min-height-65" >
```

And defined the directive ,

```
function modalIngredients($ionicModal) {
    return {
        restrict:'A',
        scope:{
            modalName:'='
        },
        controller:function($scope) {
            $scope.closeCustomModal = function() {
                $scope.modal.hide();
            }
        },
        link:function(scope,elem,attr) {
            $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/'+attr.modalName+'.html', {
                scope: scope.externalScope,
                animation: 'slide-in-up'
            }).then(function(modal) {
                scope.modal = modal
            });

            elem.bind('click',function() {
               scope.modal.show();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that once the template loads , and the Modal shows , I am not able to access the controller within the modal . I want logic of the modal specified within the controller of the directive and act according to the scope values . How to do it ?